# ArcGIS does not correctly read projection from Lidar LAS file

Tags: arcgis, lidar

I have come across a vexing issue where ArcGIS does not correctly read the projection from a LAS file.

To replicate my issue...

1. Download this Pennsylvania LAS file: ftp://pamap.pasda.psu.edu/pamap_lidar/cycle1/LAS/South/2007/10000000/19002110PAS.zip
2. View the LAS header or ENVI or similar.  You will see that the projection is State Plane PA South, the false easting is 1968500, and the units are feet.  This is correct and matches the published metadata.
3. Create a LAS dataset in ArcCatalog (right click on a folder --> New --> LAS Dataset). Next load the above LAS file into the LAS dataset. Click on the little box below Statistics to view the LAS File Properties and Statistics. Note the false easting is 600000 and the units are meters.  Incorrect!  Nothing will overlay.

How do I get ArcGIS to correctly read this LAS file? (It's for a student lab exercise, so it needs to be in ArcGIS)

Thanks for any help you can give!
-RVP

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using this tool! http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d8782286e3c9442bb5c244bf39da5966  But I still don't know why ArcGIS is reading the headers incorrectly.